# What did they mean in "Looks like someone forgot to do laundry"?

Tags: plot-explanation, orange-is-the-new-black

In episode 1 of season 5 (Riot FOMO) of Orange is the New Black, there is a scene where Sophia see Humphrey's groin and says in kind of disgust:

> Looks like someone forgot to do laundry

(Link to full transcript of the episode for context [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=orange-is-the-new-black&episode=s05e01)).

Now I didn't get what she meant by this. I didn't notice any dirty clothing there. So is this some kind of internal humor/pun of Orange is the New Black which I've missed?

Comment: Haven't seen the scene in question, but... is Humphrey wearing trousers at the time?  If not, she's probably telling him that his penis needs a wash.

Comment: @Tim pretty sure trousers were removed before. Maybe there was glimpse of underwear which I missed. But yeah, penis was widely exposed there and stained with blood (sorry for possible spoiler) I just don't see how "laundry" can be used in that context?

Comment: She's literally saying that he should have washed his penis.  That's all.  Just using laundry as a euphemism for washing something.  In this case, his dick.  Nothing to do with clothing.

Comment: @Tim huh. Thanks, so this is actually English issue. Think there is point in turning this into answer? Or better to delete the question?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because he was not wearing any underwear.

Comment: @FranciscoV. oh my. That might be, the scene showing all of this was really short but good chance you're correct. Still, not sure how not wearing underwear can cause such a comment? Maybe I miss something trivial, lol.

Comment: @ShadowWizard forgot to laundry -> no clean underpants left -> does not wear underpants

Comment: @FranciscoV. huh, makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Sophia cut open his pants to get to

> the gunshot wound in his leg

Humpfrey's penis is widely exposed due to him not wearing any underwear. Sophia makes a pun about him not having any clean underwear to wear => "forgot to do the laundry"

Edit: She is probably making that joke to convince herself that he is not roaming the women prison with nothing under his pant for the thrill of it (which I strongly believe he does)

Comment: Heh, thanks. Is this a common phrase in English? Because it's the first time I see it.

Comment: I don't think it's a common phrase in English (You don't usually rip off someone pants as they happen to not be wearing anything under) but I am pretty sure I heard it a couple times in roughly the same context in other movies/shows.

Comment: Thanks, might ask a separate question then on ELL/ELU only about the term/phrase. :-)

Comment: No problem ^^ Good luck with that

Comment: Took a while, but I finally [did it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136522/does-forgot-to-do-the-laundry-really-mean-one-walking-without-underwear). :)